# Powershell script to auto-fill fields in website

Tags: powershell

I have written below script, but after executing it, fields are grayed out and asking me to fill again manually.

Why am I getting field in grayed colour?

```
$ie.Document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('username')[0].value = "XYZAWS'"
$ie.Document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('password')[0].value = "EFGH"
```

**output**:

[image]

After clicking in fields, auto populated value was lost.

[image]